# Android Studio randomly switches branch filter in git log panel

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When I checkout some branch, fetch or just refresh git-log panel in Android Studio - IDE suddenly switch branch-filter to some random branch. So instead of seeing branch I have checked out I see some random old branch. And every time I have to switch branch-filter selector into "all branches" value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Open project workspace file ($PROJECT_DIR/.idea/workspace.xml) in any text editor
3. Find `<component name="BranchesTreeState">` and remove it (until `</component>` tag)
4. Reopen Android Studio

No more random branch-filter switches

P.S. Editing workspace.xml in Android Studio itself isn't working, because IDE immediately overwrite any changes in the file.